# How to configure xamp tomcat with jasper report server?

Tags: tomcat, jasperserver

I installed jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.1 on windows 32bit OS, but I was not given the option of selecting the existing tomcat configuration.

I already have tomcat on xampp v3.2.1, but after installing jasper reports server it's tomcat conflicts with the tomcat ports of xampp. I have googled but failed to get an answer.

How can I configure jasper reports server to use the existing tomcat server ports of xampp.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [jasper reports install guide](http://community.jaspersoft.com/modal_forms/nojs/jf-user-login-register?optoutdest=https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperserver/files/JasperServer/JasperReports%20Server%20Community%20Edition%206.2.1/JasperReports-Server-CP-Install-Guide.pdf/download), page 11-17 have some things that stand out to me (section 1.4.1.3 Installing with Existing Components)

> **1.4.1.3 Installing with Existing Components** The installer can use either bundled or existing instances of both the Apache Tomcat
>   application server and the PostgreSQL database: • If you want to use
>   an existing Tomcat, it must be on the local machine. • If you want to
>   use an existing PostgreSQL, it can be on a local or remote machine. If
>   it’s on a remote Linux machine, configure PostgreSQL to allow remote
>   connections as described in 2.7.4, “Enabling Connections to a Remote
>   Host,” on page 20. For information about specific versions of
>   third-party applications supported by the installer, refer to the
>   JasperReports Server release notes in the root of the installation
>   directory.

Further down, in chapter 2.1 it says

> Pre-installation Steps When you run the installation executable, you
>   can choose to install the bundled Apache Tomcat application server and
>   PostgreSQL database or use an existing Tomcat and PostgreSQL. If you
>   want to use an existing database instance, the database must be
>   running at install time. If you want to use an existing Apache Tomcat,
>   the Tomcat instance must be stopped. If you choose to install the
>   bundled Tomcat and database, both are installed on the same host as
>   the server. The bundled installer is not meant for use in Enterprise
>   Production environments.

The details of that step are on page 16/17 and read as

> Custom Install: With the custom install, you have the following
>   choices: install a Bundled Tomcat or use an Existing Tomcat, install a
>   Bundled PostgreSQL or use an Existing PostgreSQL, choose ports for
>   Tomcat and PostgreSQL, and choose whether or not to install sample
>   data.

I haven't tried to re-install the server in a while, but I suspect that you chose **Install All Option** and not the **Custom Install**.